# Typedoc duplicate identifier

Tags: node.js, angular, typedoc

I tried to generate a doc with typedoc plugin.
The command `npx typedoc --out docs` return this error :

```
Error: C:/Users/chemi/Desktop/AngularProject/Interv-App/node_modules/cordova-plugin-file/types/index.d.ts(375)
 Duplicate identifier 'PERSISTENT'.
Error: C:/Users/chemi/Desktop/AngularProject/Interv-App/node_modules/cordova-plugin-file/types/index.d.ts(376)
 Duplicate identifier 'TEMPORARY'.
Error: C:/Users/chemi/Desktop/AngularProject/Interv-App/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/types/index.d.ts(375)
 Duplicate identifier 'PERSISTENT'.
Error: C:/Users/chemi/Desktop/AngularProject/Interv-App/plugins/cordova-plugin-file/types/index.d.ts(376)
 Duplicate identifier 'TEMPORARY'.
```

How can I fix it ?
Thanks

Comment: This is a typescript error. Ensure that typescript compiles successfully. It may be caused because the version of typescript that typedoc is different than your project.